# How to get spicey flavour from black peppers in stew?

Tags: pepper

The piperine in black pepper has a tangy/spicy flavor and I read that it concentrates in the black part of the peppercorn and not the inner white part.

This being the case I was thinking maybe it would be a good idea to boil the peppercorns to extract the black parts.  However I put one in my mouth and whirled it around however I didnt really get any spicy flavour.  But when I cracked it it become more tangy.

Why is this if the piperine is in the black part and if its the pipirine im after/want to be in the stew liquid, would it make more sense to put a lot of whole ones and boil it, or groud it then add?

Comment: Would an extract work?  I've made a black pepper extract to add to a bourbon drink -- I don't remember particulars, which is why this is only a comment and not an answer, but I think I soaked cracked and whole black peppers in vodka, then strained?  This may be a way to add the black-pepper tang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most pronounced pepper flavor, you would want to grind and add at service.  As you cook black pepper bitter notes come out.  Some people like that black pepper bitterness, but last minute addition is what will get you the flavor and aroma of black pepper.

Comment: Thanks moscafj i'm aware of that however im still thinking about the original question as adding at serve doesnt really make the stew liquid taste bitter, i want the liquid to become bitter.  will the bitterness come out better whole vs fresh ground cooked?

Comment: If you are seeking bitterness (which the original question does not mention), I would recommend grinding to increase surface area, and include during cooking.

Comment: Piperine is volatile, so if you cook it it will evaporate and you'll lose the peppery tang. Use freshly, finely ground pepper added at service.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza you seem to be implying all the piperine will go or most of it such that no more tang will be left.  According to this it's a minority https://www.turmericforhealth.com/turmeric-queries/does-cooking-destroy-curcumin-and-piperine however based on taste Id have to agree the tang go after cooking.  Have you seen evidence to suggest most if not all the piperine will go during cooking?  Thanks

Comment: @JamesWilson flavors are very complex entities, depending on chemical composition, ratio, as well as extraction methods and processing. Evidence I have? Chemical data sheet :)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza so I guess it's not possible to get the spiciness\pipirine of black pepper or long pepper into an oil or water since the heating will just make it go?  likewise things like infusion will not work either?

Comment: @JamesWilson you should avoid extraction methods that involve heat if you want the spiciness. Infusion can be done hot (like tea) or cold (like herby, peppery or garlicky oils), and it depends 100% on WHAT you're infusing.